# ajaxSetup() call has no desired effect

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

So I'm turning on token-based auth for my REST API calls to my web server.

First I get the token when logging in:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/api/v1.0/token",
     dataType: "json",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: 'json',
     headers: {
     "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
     },
```

And when the call succeeds, I save the token and try to make it a default parameter to future ajax calls:

```
     success: function (data){
         $.ajaxSetup({
             headers: {
                 "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(data.token + ":")
             },
         });
         window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
         window.location = 'http://' + window.location.host;
```

I got no error in the console so the call succeeded. But following ajax calls still fails and I see no `Authentication` header in the debugger.

I have read in the official jquery documentation that this API is not recommended but it should still work, right? Oh, I'm using jquery 1.8.1.

If I'm doing something wrong, please help me find it. If there is a better way of achieving the same thing, I'm all ears too.

Comment: Most browsers probably don't care, but it might help to remove the extra comma after `headers`

Comment: thanks but didn't work.

Comment: 1) You're changing the page location before running the `$.ajaxSetup()` line, and 2) I don't think that persists across pages anyway. Try saving it in a cookie or in local storage.

Comment: @JasonP is correct...but you already are saving in session storage so `$.ajaxSetup` needs to run in pages after checking for token in storage. It's not even going to be called after `window.location` in code shown, let alone do any good on subsequent pages

Comment: Ah, missed that the first time.

Comment: I've moved the call to before changing `window.location` but it's still the same.

Comment: @lang2 `$.ajaxSetup()` doesn't persist across page loads. You'll need to do that on the page that you redirect to.